# Check SelectIndexChange/Blur Event In Jquery AutoComplete Combobox in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

How can I get/check `SelectIndexChange()` or `Blur()` event In Jquery AutoComplete Combobox in MVC4 ?

Answer (score 2):

You can bind on event Close ( it same blur ) and Select with call action through ajax request

View

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  select: function( event, ui ) { $.post(urlSelect); },
  close: function( event, ui ) { $.post(urlClose); }
});
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult OnSelect()
{ // something }

public ActionResult OnClose()
{ // something }
```